# Does Craft Commerce support One Time Password and Social Login features?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, registration, authentication, plugin-social-login

I have just started reviewing this plugin for e-commerce development. Fully featured though it is, I wanted to know if Craft Commerce can also support custom auth (login and registration) features such as **One Time Password** using a mobile cell number and **Social Login** through facebook and twitter?

Is it possible to build or use an existing plugin around these features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft Pro gives you the ability to add multiple user accounts to your site. Craft Commerce is a plugin that extends Craft so user accounts and everything that goes with them are available to use.

There is a [plugin to enable social logins](https://dukt.net/craft/social) (currently in beta) made by Dukt that you may find helpful.